# Create a inputbox which writes to textarea(php)

Tags: javascript, textarea

Just for fun am I creating a chatroom for one of my school classes.
What I'm after is a JavaScript, with a inputbox which pops up, once a button (add url) is pushed, where the user can paste a url which then gets written in the textarea.

I want this feature just so "http://" gets placed in front of the added url.

Been trying with this script (which looks correct to me... but it doesn't work)

```
<input type="button" id="s_5" onclick="addUrl()">
<script>
function addUrl()
{
var x;

var nettside=prompt("Type in URL:","www.example.com");

if (nettside!=null)
  {
  x="http://" + nettside + ";
  document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=x;
  }
}
</script>
```

yeah, the textarea it's supposed to write to:

```
<textarea name="txt" id="area" class="typo_vind" placeholder="......" autofocus title="Type your message here, have a great day!"></textarea>
```

****EDIT****

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="s_5" onclick="javascript:formatText(addUrl())">
```

JS:

```
<script>
function addUrl()
{
var x;

var nettside=prompt("Skriv inn lenkeadressen her:","www.testtest.com");

if (nettside!="")
  {
  x="<a href="+"http://" + nettside + ">" + "BESKRIVELSE AV LENKEN" + "</a>";
  document.getElementById("area").value=x;
  }
}
</script>
```

Two problems remains.

1. I don't want that script to clean out the textarea
2. I don't want the `<undefined></undefined>` to get added to the end
   This is the result with the script as it is now:

*`<a href=http://www.eksempel.com>__BESKRIVELSE_AV_LENKEN__</a><undefined></undefined>`*

****EDIT 2****

Solved the  problem where the script cleaned out the texarea with this:

```
<script>
function addUrl()
{
var x;

var nettside=prompt("Skriv inn lenkeadressen her (uten http://):","www.eksempel.com");

  {
  x="<a target =_blank href=http://" + nettside + ">" + "__BESKRIVELSE_AV_LENKEN__" + "</a>";
  var Field = document.getElementById('area');
  var val = Field.value;
  var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
  var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
  var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
  Field.value = before_txt  + x + after_txt;

  }
}
</script>
```

So now all that's missing is removal of the `<undefined></undefined>`-tags.

HTML: `<input type="button" id="s_5" onclick="javascript:addUrl()">`

**SOLVED!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the console of your browser - it always notifies about what error has occurred.

You have a typo in this line:

```
  x="http://" + nettside + ";
```

The ending `+ "` should be deleted.

---

Also, here:

```
document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=x;
```

you should use `value` instead (normally you do this with for elements):

```
document.getElementById("area").value=x;
```

This might not cause problems in the browser you are using, but might lead to strange behaviour under certain circumstances :).

Comment: oh, yeah, didn't see that, thank you :) now it gives me "<undefined></undefined>" hehe^^ Oh well, a step closer, atleast it writes something

Comment: edited it some, it almost works now, there are just two minor problems, first - once the button is pressed, the entire text-area gets cleared out, and also the following "<undefined></undefined>"

Comment: Figured out the last problem (stacking two scripts wich did the same thing). The "first" script didn't get defined by the value wich the second script requested. So, once again, thank you for all the help :)! Have a great weekend!